# Where can I find the command "udevinfo" on Debian?

Tags: debian, debian-wheezy, udev

I'm trying to fix a problem with my webcam in Wheezy, and I need some information about the drive with the command `udevinfo`.
The problem is: where is this executable?

if I run `sudo udevinfo` the result is:

> udevinfo: command not found

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Debian web infrastructure supports [searching packages by their contents](http://www.debian.org/distrib/packages#search_contents).

The same result can be achieved using the [`apt-file`](https://packages.debian.org/source/stretch/apt-file) tool.

**Update:** I was too confident you just don't know how to find a relevant package. In fact, this tool really was replaced by `udevadm info` as [this post](http://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2010/07/msg01134.html) explains.

Comment: I'm reading all... :)

Comment: Lnk is down (apt-file) :-(

Comment: @philippe-gachoud, [here we go](http://packages.debian.org/apt-file).

Answer (score 5):

`udevadm info` **is the new command**. that replaces udevinfo

The arguments are same as `udevinfo`.

Answer (score 2):

```
udevadm info -a
```

Does what `udevinfo -a -p` used to do

Answer (score 1):

The answer above is incomplete: if you're like me, you're here because you have found yourself using some script (perhaps a "configure" script) that parses the output of udevinfo to ensure that udev is recent enough. 
In that case, the arguments to "udevadm info" and "udevinfo" might be the same, but the output isn't. For me, it was enough to replace the original line:

```
udev_ver=`udevinfo -V | awk '{ print $3 }'`
```

with

udev_ver=`udevadm info -V | awk '{ print $1 }'`

The script with this modification ran without errors, and I was able to get on with the rest of my life :).